# How to identify transistor code marking Y2Z?

Tags: transistors, identification

How can I identify the bipolar transistor with marking code Y2Z? How to translate what is the Y2Z code mean?

Comment: Please provide a picture and dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Without a picture of the part or the surrounding circuit, it is almost impossible to provide a definite answer.  However, are you sure it is a BPT?

The code Y2Z could also correspond with a 12V BZX84 Zener from NXP in a SOT23 package.